# Is it possible to alert user if a certain marker is on the route they have created?

Tags: google-maps, routes, maps, markers

I am creating a routing web app that contains markers for low bridges, I would like to alert the user that there is a low bridge on the route they have selected. I am aware it is not possible to create avoid points, although Google already have avoid for tolls and highways. Any help much be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You may use  [`google.maps.geometry.poly.isLocationOnEdge`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en&csw=1#poly)

Call it for the position of each marker.

Comment: Thanks Dr.Molle. I ended up using Routeboxer. It creates box along the route created and you can check if a marker is within these boxes.

Answer (score -1):

I used RouteBoxer to create boxes along the route and to check if the point was within in the boxes. Box sizes can be set to increase speed (bigger boxes means less boxes check) / accuracy (bigger boxes means that less accuracy).